# Managing Shared and Local object repositories in QTP testing

Tags: automated-tests, qtp

I am testing a windows UI application with a lot of menus. I think I understand the concept of shared and local OR but I feel its a lot of work maintaining the shared OR and it outweighs the advantage i.e. memory usage.

Scenario : If I record the operations in 'File' menu, I can see that a window object, File menu object and some dialog objects that show up after that are created in LOR. At this point, I feel only the window object is a candidate for SOR because only that is a reusable object. So I merge my LOR and SOR. Then, I create a new action to record 'Edit' menu tests. I associated the SOR with this action. At, this point its fine. But when I look at the OR of Edit action after recording, I see that the Window object is local now. So I have to go back and again merge LOR and SOR. Unless I am doing something wrong, this means I have to keep doing this merge for every test/action till every object or sub object I would possibly use would be in the SOR. This is not helpful at all. Am I missing some concept here?

Thanks for reading and any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The motivation for using SORs is not to reduce memory usage but to increase sharing so that if something changes in the application you only need to fix the description in one place.

For this reason one would typically use SORs when creating tests using keyword driven testing and not recording. 
Usually one would have the entire area of the application in the SOR (or not at all) and not just the test objects which are actually shared.